# How do you make your AWS ELB internal in a AWS Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I am templating an EB app and several environments. I want to ensure that the ELB is set to be internal, but cant find the reference in the Cloudformation documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an internal Elastic Load Balancer within an Elastic Beanstalk application by setting the `ELBScheme` property in the EB's [`aws:ec2:vpc` namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc):

> Specify `internal` if you want to create an internal load balancer in your VPC so that your Elastic Beanstalk application cannot be accessed from outside your VPC.

To configure this within a CloudFormation template, add the option to the [`OptionSettings`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-optionsettings) property of your [`AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html) resource:

```
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
Properties: 
  ApplicationName: !Ref AppName
  SolutionStackName: !Ref SolutionStackName
  OptionSettings: 
    - 
      Namespace: "aws:ec2:vpc"
      OptionName: ELBScheme
      Value: internal
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the "Scheme" parameter: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#cfn-ec2-elb-scheme

Accepts either 'internal' or 'internet-facing' as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the this. However, is there a way to set that in an Elasticbeanstalk (EB) cloudformation template? When you specify an EB configuration?

Comment: See @wjordan's answer above. It's the same idea, just called 'ELBScheme' there.